# Alinhar divs de acordo com a class

Tags: css

Tenho uma `div` pai com várias `divs` filho dentro.
E gostaria que as divs com a class azul ficassem à direita e as com a class branco ficassem a esquerda. Porém uma ao lado da outra, como numa fila.
Colocando as class para flutuar à esquerda e à direita fica um espaço entre.

```css
.pai{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
.filho{
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.azul{
  float:left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.branco{
  float:right;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='pai'>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
</div>
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim, mas não controlo a ordem das divs.

```css
.pai{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
.filho{
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.azul{
  float:left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.branco{
  float:left;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='pai'>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho azul'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
   <div class='filho branco'>texto</div>
</div>
```

Como fazer ?

Comment: Pode ser com flex?

Comment: Eu bem pensei nisso, mas tentei aplicar na div pai, não deu muito certo. Pode me dar um exemplo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com `display:flex` no pai vc pode usar o atributo `order` nos filhos, todos os filhos por padrão tem `order 0`, então basta vc colocar nos filhos que forem `azul order:1` e nos filhos `branco order:2`, dessa forma tudo que for azul vai vir antes, independente da ordem das tag no HTML.

Veja:

```css
.pai {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filho {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.azul {
    /* float: left; */
    background-color: blue;
    /* tode que é azul vem primeiro order:1 */
    order: 1;
}

.branco {
    /* float: right; */
    background-color: white;
    /* vem depois de tudo que for order:1 */
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filho azul">texto</div>
    <div class="filho branco">texto</div>
    <div class="filho azul">texto</div>
    <div class="filho azul">texto</div>
    <div class="filho branco">texto</div>
    <div class="filho branco">texto</div>
    <div class="filho branco">texto</div>
    <div class="filho azul">texto</div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o atributo `order`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado

Comment: @PedroAugusto agora vc já tem uma opção, vamos ver se mais alguém tira uma carta da manga rss